# MemSQL Column Store Table Disk vs. Memory

Tags: amazon-s3, singlestore, columnstore

I have a cluster with 8 m3.2xlarge leaf nodes (2x80 SSD, 30GB RAM).

About my data:

- I have one database
- I have one columnstore table.
- My data resides in s3.
- S3 file size is 250GB.
- The data is split in 40 6GB files.

When I try to load this data into the table, the import process fails after loading around 60GB (10 files) of data. At this point, the Leaf MemSQL Memory is almost full (212GB). Disk capacity is 1.64TB but only around 150GB is used.

It is my understanding that ColumnStore table resides in disk. If that's the case, why is the disk not filling up and instead, leaf memory is running out?

A few things to note:

- The import process keeps trying to process the rest of the files and loads part of the data in each file and fails.
- Of the 8 leaf nodes only 2 of them fill up the memory completely (27 out of 30GB). The rest are at around 17GB
- I used cloudformation to setup the cluster and all parameters are set
  to the default values.

Am I configuring things incorrectly?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ram.

Comment: What version of MemSQL are you using?

Comment: We are doing a POC, so the cluster was terminated. I can't check now.. but i believe we were using 5.7.

Comment: I'd recommend testing on the v6 beta, memory usage during load on a columnstore table should be much better there.

Comment: You should post the DDL used for the tables to confirm the columnstore is properly setup.